# c# retrieve images from folder into picturebox

Tags: c#

I am new to coding and I was wondering if it is possible to add a folder with images to c# web form application without putting it all in resources, accessing it through "C:/" or from image list. 
I've tried on image list from toolbox however it has its limitation because of the image size.

Comment: You are right, ImageList can only hold one size which can only be 256x256 pixels. Instead you will want to read in the list of filenames and load each file only when it is needed. Make sure to dispose of them or you will soon run out of space and/or gdi resources..!!

Comment: I placed the images in "Graph Images" and I want to retrieve them without the "c:\" and I want to get each image with the use of combobox too. But I'm not sure of the code to access that folder. How do I use the filename? or is there a way for me to retrieve the images through "bin\debug" if i put the folder there